# Do more unnecessary variables in Python mean more memory usage?

Tags: python, variables, memory, memory-management

Let's say I have some code like this:

```
default_pos = (21,45)
#I do some more stuff now, then change my mind to change the default_pos
#So, I overwrite default_pos and assign something else to it
default_pos = (756,600)
```

What if instead of this I declared a new variable called `default_pos_changed` and left the old one just how it is? That would mean an unnecessary variable. So,wouldn't it use up a bit more memory than needed? Now, if there were hundreds of unused variables like this, it might be a problem, right?

Comment: You just changed your post to ask a completely different question :(

Comment: Sorry, it was a bit unclear

Comment: The answer depends not on the language, but on the interpreter. `CPython`, `PyPy`, `IronPython`, ...?

Comment: I'm using CPython, didn't like the sound of IronPython. Using CPython for over an year. Never head problems

Comment: Variables : Variables are known at the runtime only, unless they are global or constant. Heap memory allocation scheme is used for managing allocation and de-allocation of memory for variables in runtime. [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_runtime_environment.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call a *variable* is actually a *reference* to an object. So, using a new variable like `default_pos_changed` consumes some memory. But, only the memory to store the reference, not the object itself.

You can take a look to the [C implementation of Python](https://github.com/python/cpython) on GitHub. A *reference* is essentially a pointer (and additional info), so its size is around the size of a pointer. On 64 bit machine it 8 bytes. It’s small compared to the referenced object size.

**Edit**

You can use `del` to free the memory: the reference is deleted and if the number of references to an object is nul, the object allocated memory can be free too according to the garbage collector rules.

```
del default_pos_changed. # free the reference memory
del default_pos. # free the reference memory, the object can be garbage collected.
```

Comment: However, keeping a bunch of variables around, especially in the global scope, means that the objects they refer to won't be deallocated. Probably worth mentioning that. But yes, it is a good point that even hundres of "unecessary" variables would only take up a few kilobytes.

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about `del`, I was just curious about the variables.